# ChangeTracker.Entries<T> not returning entries with entities of Type T

Tags: entity-framework-4, change-tracking

using EF 4.3.1 in SaveChanges(), i'm trying to get a list of all entries for entities which implement a specific interface. My entities implement multiple interfaces, one of which is IAuditable. The following doesn't return any entries, even though entries with entities of type IAuditable do exist.

```
 var auditableEntities =
                ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>().Where(
                    e => e.State == EntityState.Modified | e.State == EntityState.Added);
```

Comment: The `|` should be `||` so  `e => e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Added`

Comment: i've changed it, still doesn't work. I would assume if i do this - context.EntitySet<MyEntityType>().Add(anEntity) that would mean that after ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() is called the ChangeTracker.Entries list would have entries. Is that correct?

Comment: found the issue - after i assign to auditableEntities, i call base.SaveChanges() which changes the entity states in my collection to unchanged. Question - i'm assigning the states to a variable auditableEntities - THEN i call SaveChanges(). Why does it update my variable auditableEntities?