# ChangeTracker equivalent on Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I would like to log added records using Entity Framework

Table1

```
CatID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
----------------------------------
1     | a    | b    | c    | d    |
----------------------------------
```

Code for saving

```
var context = new DBEntities();
Table1 obj1 = new Table1{
Col1 = "a", Col2 = "b"
};
context.Table1.AddObject(obj1)
context.SaveChanges();
```

Dummy code for saving audit

```
var propWithValue = //get only Col1 and Col2
foreach(var list1 in propWithValue)
{
     //save audit
}
```

How can i do this in EF4?

Comment: are you sure it dosn't?  seems to exist i this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970257/changetracker-entriest-not-returning-entries-with-entities-of-type-t

Comment: I edited my question @John thank you